# Use SQL subquery to count number of rows in table and pass/fail java test based on the result

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, subquery

Below are 2 of my SQL Server tables.

Taddress

```
addressId | addressName |
2         | testAddress |
```

Tlink

```
linkId | clientId | addressId |
1      | 4        | 2         |
```

I am trying to write a java test that  uses an SQL sub-query to check if a record exists in taddress.

For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Taddress
WHERE addressId =
(SELECT addressId FROM Tlink
WHERE clientId = param)
```

At the moment, when I run the below test, the test always passes even if the clientId parameter doesn't exist in tLink.

```
try {
        dbAccessSetUp();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM taddress a INNER JOIN tlink l on a.address_id = l.internal_address_id WHERE l.ext_client_id =" + this.clientNo);

        if(!rs.next()) {
            fail("Record does not exist in taddress based on ExtClientNo");
        }

        int count = 0;

        while(rs.next()) {              

            count = rs.getInt(1);
            System.out.println("number of count : " + count);
            assertTrue(0 < count);
        } 
        rs.close(); 
    } catch(SQLException se) { 
        se.printStackTrace(); 
        assertEquals(true, false);
    } catch(Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
        assertEquals(true, false);
    } finally { 
        try { 
            if(stmt!=null) stmt.close();  
        } catch(SQLException se2) {
            assertEquals(true, false);
        } 
        try { 
            if(conn!=null) conn.close(); 
        } catch(SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace(); 
            assertEquals(true, false);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Are you passing a particular value in place of param?

Comment: @Mohan Hi, yes that will be a value passed in from a cucumber feature file. So if a valid value (a value that matches a clientId in tLink) was passed in as param, then I want to use the addressId of that row to count the number of rows in Taddress. Also, if an invalid value (a value that does not match a clientId in tLink) then I want the test to fail

Comment: Basically, I want the test to fail if there is no record in tLink for that clientId and I want the test to fail if there is no matching record in tAddress also

Comment: Have you done any debugging to see what `rs.getInt(1)` is returning for your test cases?

Comment: I am quite surprised how the test always passes. You might need to print the value of count as MatBailie pointed out and see if it returns greater than zero for invalid values

Comment: **If** `param` is passed correctly, then your SQL statement is correct and so is this: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Taddress WHERE EXISTS (SELECT addressId FROM Tlink WHERE clientId = param)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code examples above, this should work for you:

```
try {
        dbAccessSetUp();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*)FROM taddress A INNER JOIN tlink L ON A.address_id = L.internal_address_id WHERE L.ext_client_id =" + this.clientNo);
        int count=0;
        while(rs.next()) {
            count =  ((Number) rs.getObject(1)).intValue();

        }

        if(count > 0) {
            assertTrue(true);
            System.out.println(count + " record(s) in taddress based on ExtClientNo");
        }
        else {
            fail("No records in taddress");
        }

    }catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

This will fail if:

- There are no matching records in tlink for your clientNo
- There is a matching record in tlink, but there is no matching records in taddress

This will pass if:

- There is a matching record in tlink & there is a matching record in taddress

Answer (score 0):

For your query it will run without error until you have more than 1 row in `Tlink` table, so it's better to change it to a simple join as

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Taddress A INNER JOIN Tlink L ON A.addressId = L.addressId
WHERE L.clientId = Param;
```

Now, we agree that the query will return the right result, but your Java code is not working as expected as you mention

> At the moment, when I run a test using the above query, the test always passes even if the clientId parameter doesn't exist in tLink.

The query above will return just one row (one value), so you don't need to loop and this code is useless

```
while(rs.next()){
    count = rs.getInt(1);
    assertTrue(0 < count);
}
```

all what you need there is get the value returned by the query and check if it's greater than `0` or not, something like

```
count =  ((Number) rs.getObject(1)).intValue();
int cmp;
if (count > 0)
// Exists;
else 
//Not exists;
```

Or

```
assertTrue(count.equals(0));
```

Comment: Yup, did not understand the question for first time.

Comment: That is indeed a better SQL Statement.  It ***won't***, however, change the result compared to how the OP wrote it, so what change the behaviour in the Java

Comment: @MatBailie Do you mean the OP want an answer with Java code?

Comment: @Sami - Read the question!  They want a test in Java to see if certain records exist. Your SQL will return ***exactly*** the same results as their SQL.  So, this achieves ***nothing***.  It's better SQL, but makes ***zero*** difference to the behaviour the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Sami thanks for your answer, are you able to provide a java test method that would work with your join?

Comment: Or do I literally just need to assign the value returned by the query to an integer, and assert that the integer is greater than zero?

Comment: @Sweg     The issue could be because of a record with address as empty exist in the Taddress table

Comment: All records in taddress are populated

Comment: So if I slot in this code, will the test fail if there is no record in tLink for the parameter passed in? Will the test fail if there is no record in Taddress for the record in tLink? And will the test pass if there is 1 record in Taddress

Comment: Hi @Sami I've tried your solution below: `try {
   dbAccessSetUp();
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*)FROM taddress A INNER JOIN tlink L ON A.address_id = L.internal_address_id WHERE L.ext_client_id = 6969696");
   int count =  ((Number) rs.getObject(1)).intValue();
   System.out.println("the count is equal to = " + count);
  }catch(Exception ex) {
   System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
  }` But the catch prints out: **No data is available**

Answer (score 0):

Make your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM taddress a INNER JOIN tlink l on a.addressid = l.addressID
WHERE l.clientid = @param
```

This will return 0 if either:

- no tlink for that param
- no taddress for that tlink

If you want to know where the relationship broke down:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count_link, COUNT(a.addressid) as count_address 
FROM taddress a RIGHT JOIN tlink l on a.addressid = l.addressID
WHERE l.clientid = @param
```

Regarding your assertion that the count is always > 0 regardless of what @param you pass, i'd like to see some additional debug/screenshot/printout etc that indicates that

Edit

So the problem with your code is:

You run the sql and you then call `if(!rs.hasNext())`

Your resultset does have a row, so the call to rs.next returns true, you negate this so the if test returns false, the if does not run, and your resultset is now pointing to the first line of data from the query. **The ONLY line of data** - you ought to now read the data but you don’t...

Next you say `while(rs.hasNext())` this advances your resultset another line, so it is no longer pointing to the count data. There are no more rows of data so this call returns false and **your while loop body never runs** -you never pull any data out of the result set, your assert is never run etc etc

Re-work your code so that you do your assert() in the first if and ditch the while loop

```
if(rs.next())
  assert(rs.getInt(1) > 0);
```

A count query of this form will always return one row, there’s little point testing the resultset to have no data. If the query fails to run an exception will generate instead

Comment: That is indeed a better SQL Statement.  It ***won't***, however, change the result compared to how the OP wrote it, so won't change the behaviour in the Java

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would this query work if I slot it into my method above, or so I need to make changes to the method? I.e. throw in try/catch, etc.?

Comment: 1. Test should pass if a record exists in taddress using the query. 2. Test should fail if no record exists in tLink for that parameter. 3. Test should fail if there is no record in taddress for the addressId which is retrieved from tLink

Comment: If you're using the second form you might want to add a `rs.getInt(2)` to retrieve the count of address records, and write some additional logic to test that result too..

Comment: i.e. `assertTrue(rs.getInt(1) > 0 && rs.getInt(2) > 0)` if using the second form. `assertTrue(rs.getInt(1) > 0)` would be fine for the first form

Comment: Note also that you should adjust the parameter naming style (@param) in accordance with the database/driver you're using. It might need to be like `?` depending on the db/driver combination - i can't remember which db drivers in java use `?` for parameters instead of `@named_parameters`

Comment: Hi @CaiusJard I have added your SQL join to my code & posted it above. But, the above test is passing regardless of the parameter I pass

Comment: @CaiusJard If I replace _this.clientNo_ with any number, the test will pass regardless

Comment: Not quite, you call rs.next() twice, and as a result you end up never running the test at all. It’s not that it passes, it’s that it never runs (same end result but subtly different effect), see my edit to the answer for Moreno info why